# Joining character array elements

Tags: arrays, powershell

An alphanumeric string is input, sent to lower, then evaluated.  Then, every third letter needs to be capitalized and returned to a string.  The number/letter positions are not always the same.

Sample input handling:

```
$in = read-host "value in"
$var1 = $in.tolower()
```

So I've given two variables that can be used as an example

```
$var1 = 1ab23c4def56
# $var1 = a123bcd45e6f  # alternate $var1 for example purposes

$val = ($var1).ToCharArray()

foreach ($n in $val){
    if ($n -notmatch "[0-9]"){
        $alfaNo++
        if ($alfaNo -eq 4){
            $o = $([char]::ToUpper($n))
            $alfaNo = 0
            $n = $o
        }
        echo $n
    }
    else {echo $n}
}
$val
```

The issue is that the loop shows each appropriate character going to upper, but the change isn't made when `$val` displayed at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're dealing with Scope issues. While in the `ForEach` loop the variables are in a scope that don't affect the array that they come from. A simple modification without a complete re-write would be to simply add a new variable, and set it to be the output of your `ForEach` loop, and then have the `ForEach` loop output `$n` instead of echoing it (or in addition to).

Now, so far as I can tell your `If` statement is just wrong and the correct letters are not in fact being capitalized, but that aside this at least lets your code function as you want:

```
$var1 = "1ab23c4def56"
# $var1 = a123bcd45e6f  # alternate $var1 for example purposes

$val = ($var1).ToCharArray()
$alfaNo = 0
$NewVal = foreach ($n in $val){
    if ($n -notmatch "[0-9]"){
        $alfaNo++
        if ($alfaNo -eq 4){
            $o = $([char]::ToUpper($n))
            $alfaNo = 0
            $n = $o
        }

    }
    $n
}
$newval -join ''
```

Personally I'd use a `Switch` command instead of a `ForEach` with all those `If` statements. Something like:

```
$var1 = "1ab23c4def56"
# $var1 = a123bcd45e6f  # alternate $var1 for example purposes

$inc = 0
$NewVal = Switch($var1 -Split ''){
    {$_ -match "\d"} {$_;continue}
    {$_ -match "[a-z]" -and $inc -lt 2} {$_;$inc++;continue}
    {$_ -match "[a-z]"} {$inc = 0;[char]::toupper($_)}
}
$NewVal -join ''
```

Comment: I picked this as the best answer for three reasons:  The first option is the closest thing to my original code, I had no idea you could make a loop a variable (genius!), and your suggestion for using a switch was what I went with.

Answer (score 1):

You're modifying the value of $n but not the original array $val.

Try this...

```
$var1 = "1ab23c4def56"
# $var1 = a123bcd45e6f  # alternate $var1 for example purposes

$val = ($var1).ToCharArray()

$alfaNo = 0
for($i=0;$i -le $val.Length;$i++){
    if ($val[$i] -notmatch "[0-9]"){
        $alfaNo++
        if ($alfaNo -eq 3){
            $val[$i] = $([char]::ToUpper($val[$i]))
            $alfaNo = 0
        }
        echo $val[$i]
    }
    else {echo $val[$i]}
}
$val
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another approach.
If you want the results in String, you have to create new String object like this.

```
$var1 = '1ab23c4def56'
$val = ($var1).ToCharArray()

for( $n=0 ; $n -lt $val.length ; $n++)
{
   if( (($n % 3) -eq 2) -AND ($val[$n] -match "[a-z]") )
   {
      $val[$n] = [char]::ToUpper($val[$n])
   }
}

$var1 = New-Object System.String ($val,0,$val.Length)

$var1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
$var1 = '1ab23c4def56'

$i=0
$var1 = 
$([string[]][char[]]$var1 |
foreach { 
 if (++$i %3) { $_ }
  else { $_.ToUpper() }
 }) -join ''

$var1
```

Comment: Nice one. As a variation you could remove the subexpression and the `-join` operation and do `$OFS = ''; "$var1"` instead.

Comment: @Ansgar Weichars - Thanks!  I generally try to avoid messing with $OFS.  If I do, I usually isolate that change into it's own scope so it reverts back to whatever it was before I changed it when I'm done with it.